# sessionConnector.asp returnin code not JSON

Tags: php, session

I have

```
<%@Language=VBScript CodePage=65001%>
<!--#include file="aspJSON.asp"-->
<%
    Set JSONObject = jsObject()

    For Each Key In Session.Contents
        If Not IsObject(Session.Contents(Key)) Then 'skip the objects cannot be serialized
            JSONObject(Key) = Session.Contents(Key)
        End If
    Next

    JSONObject.Flush
%>
```

That works when I call it as I get the Session data as JSON

I have this in my PHP

````
function GetASPSessionState(){
    if(stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"], "ASPSESSIONID") === false){
        # since ASP sessions stored in memory 
        # don't make request to get ASP session state if the cookie does not contain ASPSESSIONID
        # otherwise IIS will create new redundant sessions for each of your checks so it wouldn't be a memory-friendly way
        # returning an empty array
        return array();
    } else {
        $options = array('http' => 
            array('method'=>"GET", 'header' => "Cookie: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"])
        );
        $cx = stream_context_create($options);      
        $response = file_get_contents("sessionConnector.asp", false, $cx);
    
        
    ```print_r(json_decode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
        return json_decode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }
}
````

This isn't working
$response = file_get_contents("sessionConnector.asp", false, $cx);

$response is set to

<%@Language=VBScript%> <% Set JSONObject = jsObject() For Each Key In Session.Contents If Not IsObject(Session.Contents(Key)) Then 'skip the objects cannot be serialized JSONObject(Key) = Session.Contents(Key) End If Next JSONObject.Flush %>

Why isn't it set to the JSON?

Thanks

aspJSON.asp is

```
<%
'
'   VBS JSON 2.0.3
'   Copyright (c) 2009 Tuðrul Topuz
'   Under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt) license.
'
Const JSON_OBJECT   = 0
Const JSON_ARRAY    = 1
Class jsCore
    Public Collection
    Public Count
    Public QuotedVars
    Public Kind ' 0 = object, 1 = array
    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        Set Collection = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        QuotedVars = True
        Count = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub Class_Terminate
        Set Collection = Nothing
    End Sub
    ' counter
    Private Property Get Counter
        Counter = Count
        Count = Count + 1
    End Property
    ' - data maluplation
    ' -- pair
    Public Property Let Pair(p, v)
        If IsNull(p) Then p = Counter
        Collection(p) = v
    End Property
    Public Property Set Pair(p, v)
        If IsNull(p) Then p = Counter
        If TypeName(v) <> "jsCore" Then
            Err.Raise &hD, "class: class", "Incompatible types: '" & TypeName(v) & "'"
        End If
        Set Collection(p) = v
    End Property
    Public Default Property Get Pair(p)
        If IsNull(p) Then p = Count - 1
        If IsObject(Collection(p)) Then
            Set Pair = Collection(p)
        Else
            Pair = Collection(p)
        End If
    End Property
    ' -- pair
    Public Sub Clean
        Collection.RemoveAll
    End Sub
    Public Sub Remove(vProp)
        Collection.Remove vProp
    End Sub
    ' data maluplation
    ' encoding
    Function jsEncode(str)
        Dim charmap(127), haystack()
        charmap(8)  = "\b"
        charmap(9)  = "\t"
        charmap(10) = "\n"
        charmap(12) = "\f"
        charmap(13) = "\r"
        charmap(34) = "\"""
        charmap(47) = "\/"
        charmap(92) = "\\"
        Dim strlen : strlen = Len(str) - 1
        ReDim haystack(strlen)
        Dim i, charcode
        For i = 0 To strlen
            haystack(i) = Mid(str, i + 1, 1)
            charcode = AscW(haystack(i)) And 65535
            If charcode < 127 Then
                If Not IsEmpty(charmap(charcode)) Then
                    haystack(i) = charmap(charcode)
                ElseIf charcode < 32 Then
                    haystack(i) = "\u" & Right("000" & Hex(charcode), 4)
                End If
            Else
                haystack(i) = "\u" & Right("000" & Hex(charcode), 4)
            End If
        Next
        jsEncode = Join(haystack, "")
    End Function
    ' converting
    Public Function toJSON(out, vPair)
        Select Case VarType(vPair)
            Case 0  ' Empty
                out.WriteText "null"
            Case 1  ' Null
                out.WriteText "null"
            Case 4, 5 ' Single, Double
                if (vPair < 1 AND vPair > 0) then
                    out.WriteText("0" & cStr(vPair))
                elseif (vPair > -1 AND vPair < 0) then
                    out.WriteText("-0" & cStr(vPair))
                else
                    out.WriteText(cStr(vPair))
                end if
            Case 7  ' Date
                ' toJSON = "new Date(" & (vPair - CDate(25569)) * 86400000 & ")"    ' let in only utc time
                out.WriteText """"
                out.WriteText CStr(vPair)
                out.WriteText """"
            Case 8  ' String
                out.WriteText """"
                out.WriteText jsEncode(vPair)
                out.WriteText """"
            Case 9  ' Object
                Dim bFI,i
                bFI = True
                If vPair.Kind Then out.WriteText "[" Else out.WriteText "{"
                For Each i In vPair.Collection
                    If bFI Then bFI = False Else out.WriteText ","
                    If vPair.Kind Then
                        toJSON out, vPair(i)
                    Else
                        If QuotedVars Then
                            out.WriteText """"
                            out.WriteText jsEncode(i)
                            out.WriteText """:"
                            toJSON out, vPair(i)
                        Else
                            out.WriteText i
                            out.WriteText ":"
                            toJSON out, vPair(i)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                If vPair.Kind Then out.WriteText "]" Else out.WriteText "}"
            Case 11 ' Boolean
                If vPair Then out.WriteText "true" Else out.WriteText "false"
            Case 12, 8192, 8204 ' Variant, Array, Array<Variant>
                RenderArray out, vPair, 1, ""
            Case Else
                out.WriteText Replace(vPair, ",", ".")
        End select
    End Function
    Function RenderArray(out, arr, depth, parent)
        Dim first : first = LBound(arr, depth)
        Dim last : last = UBound(arr, depth)
        Dim index, rendered
        Dim limiter : limiter = ","
        out.WriteText "["
        For index = first To last
            If index = last Then
                limiter = ""
            End If
            On Error Resume Next
            RenderArray out, arr, depth + 1, (parent & index & ",")
            If Err = 9 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                toJSON out, Eval("arr(" & parent & index & ")")
                out.WriteText limiter
            Else
                out.WriteText limiter
            End If
        Next
        out.WriteText "]"
    End Function
    Public Property Get jsString
        dim out
        set out = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        out.Type = 2 'Set type to text.'
        out.Open
        toJSON out, Me
        out.Position = 0
        jsString = out.ReadText
        out.close
        set out = nothing
    End Property
    Sub Flush
        If TypeName(Response) <> "Empty" Then
            Response.Write(jsString)
        ElseIf WScript <> Empty Then
            WScript.Echo(jsString)
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Function Clone
        Set Clone = ColClone(Me)
    End Function
    Private Function ColClone(core)
        Dim jsc, i
        Set jsc = new jsCore
        jsc.Kind = core.Kind
        For Each i In core.Collection
            If IsObject(core(i)) Then
                Set jsc(i) = ColClone(core(i))
            Else
                jsc(i) = core(i)
            End If
        Next
        Set ColClone = jsc
    End Function
End Class
Function jsObject
    Set jsObject = new jsCore
    jsObject.Kind = JSON_OBJECT
End Function
Function jsArray
    Set jsArray = new jsCore
    jsArray.Kind = JSON_ARRAY
End Function
Function toJSON(val)
    toJSON = (new jsCore).toJSON(val)
End Function
%>
```

Comment: I don’t understand how you are combining ASP Classic with PHP?

Comment: When you call file_get_contents on a file path, it is read as text. If you want it to be interpreted, you need to run it through an interpreter such as a web server, which means you’d have to have an HTTP or HTTPS protocol in front of the path.

Comment: I did try with the full path but  $response = file_get_contents("sessionConnector.asp", false, $cx) was returning false and I have no idea why. The site is protected at the moment as it is a test version but taking the protection off didn't wmake any difference it still returned false with the full path

Comment: What I mean is that you need to call `file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/path/sessionConnector.asp')`, replacing the domain and path as needed. You can read this as text that is local. It must be interpreted by the ASP processor.

Comment: That is what I have tried. I have just tried curl as well and that gives a 401  even when the site protection is removed. I am stumped

Comment: I don't know what specific "protection" you are talking about, but 401 means unauthorized, so you need to work that out with the server itself or possibly the application. Check your server logs.

Comment: The designer has some sort of protection on the whole site while it is under test. You havd to log in to access it. Taht doesn't seem to be the problem though as it still fails without it set.

Comment: $options = array('http' => 
            array('method'=>"GET", 'header' => "Cookie: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"],
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"))
        );
        $cx = stream_context_create($options);
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.blaablaa.com/admin/posts/sessionConnector.asp", false, $cx);




 if ($response === false) {
  $error = error_get_last();
  print_r($error)
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241378/discussion-between-p-whittaker-and-chris-haas).